# What Law prohibits me from doing this?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am working on a differentiation question and my answer to simplify is

$2x\ln \left(2x-1\right)+\frac{2}{2x-1}x^2$

Why cant I cancel out a x when multiplying to get 
$\frac{2x}{2-1}$= $2x$ ?

So my final answer would be 
$2x(\ln \left(2x-1\right)+1)$

Instead they factorize to get this answer
$2x\left(\frac{x}{2x-1}+\ln \left(2x-1\right)\right)$

I can recognize how they arrive at that final answer but is my answer wrong?

Comment: Because iff $\frac{2x}{2x-1} = 1, \forall x$ then $\frac{2\cdot 1}{2\cdot 1-1}=1 \implies 2=1$.

Comment: You can only cancel a factor of $ \ x \ $ from the denominator if it were present in _both_ terms of the denominator.  _This_ would be correct:  $ \ \frac{2}{2x - x} \cdot x^2 \ = \ \frac{2}{(2-1) \ x} \cdot x^2 \ = \ 2x \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x}{x+a}\neq\frac{1}{1+a}\\
\frac{x}{x\cdot a}=\frac{1}{1\cdot a}$$

Comment: Indeed.  Further $\dfrac{x}{x+a}=\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac a x}$